# Fixed navbar covered by rest of the page when scrolling down

Tags: html, css

I would like to have an element looking like a navbar at the top of my website:

[image]

It should be fixed, like a navbar. However, as soon as the user scrolls down, it should disappear under the rest of the content:

[image]

I tried something like that, where the `#title` element is the "navbar":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="title" class="center-align">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="showcase" class="center-align">
    </div>
</body>

<style>
#title {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    z-index: -1;
}

#showcase {
    margin-top: 50vh;
    height: 75vh;
    background-color: #212121;
}
</style>

</html>
```

However this is not working, the `#title` seems to be also affected by the 50vh `margin-top` (you can see it by setting its `z-index` to 1 instead of -1).

Comment: check my updated answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***No need to use z-index***

> By default sibling are stacking by the order from bottom to top so the 1st child will at the bottom, the last child at the top. See example here:

#### Example of sibling z-index:

```css
.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.div2 {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.div3 {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  div1
</div>
<div class="div2">
  div2
</div>
<div class="div3">
  div3
</div>
```

## Solution to your problem:

```css
#title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#showcase {
  margin-top: 120px;
  height: 90vh;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
</div>

<div id="showcase">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `top: 0` to the title id. Like:

```
#title {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change your style with the following css . I made some changes for test purpose.

```
    #title {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    z-index: -1;
    background: red ; 
    top:0;
}

#showcase {
    margin-top: 50vh;
    height: 275vh;
    background-color: #212121;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using a fixed navabr and a normal div for the content having a margin-top:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: lightblue;
  z-index:-1;
}

.content {
width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 1000px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar">
      Navbar
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```